# How to set pubsubTopic to get rid of SHARES_PUBSUB_TOPIC_MESSAGE_ACROSS_VERSIONS while using mybusinessnotifications.googleapis.com in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I want to read a list of notifications which google returns for a specific account. It seems that my old program is not working, and I cannot find an example for the new API.
First, we need to set what type of notifications we are interested in.Let's suppose `mybusiness` is an initializer of type `MyBusinessNotificationSettings` which also takes care of credentials:

```
 public void setNotificationTypes(String accountId, String projectId) {
        try {
            List<String> notificationTypes = Arrays.asList(
                    "GOOGLE_UPDATE", "NEW_REVIEW", "UPDATED_REVIEW", "NEW_QUESTION",
                    "UPDATED_QUESTION", "NEW_ANSWER", "UPDATED_ANSWER"
                    );

            GetNotificationSetting getSettings = mybusiness.accounts().getNotificationSetting(accountId+"/notificationSetting");
            NotificationSetting currentSettings = getSettings.execute();
            
 

            String pubSubTopic = "projects/"+projectId+"/topics/newNotification";

            currentSettings.setNotificationTypes(notificationTypes).setPubsubTopic(pubSubTopic);
            UpdateNotificationSetting updateRequest = mybusiness.accounts().
                    updateNotificationSetting(accountId + "/notificationSetting", currentSettings).setUpdateMask("pubsub_topic,notification_types");
            
            NotificationSetting updatedSettings = updateRequest.execute();


            System.out.println("Notification settings updated: " + updatedSettings);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }
```

The Error is

> POST https://mybusinessnotifications.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXX/notificationSetting?updateMask=pubsub_topic,notification_types
> {
> "code" : 400,
> "details" : [ {
> "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
> "reason" : "SHARES_PUBSUB_TOPIC_MESSAGE_ACROSS_VERSIONS"
> } ],
> "errors" : [ {
> "domain" : "global",
> "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
> "reason" : "badRequest"
> } ],
> "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
> "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }

How can I handle `SHARES_PUBSUB_TOPIC_MESSAGE_ACROSS_VERSIONS` problem?
I have checked the permissions are all correct and the **notifications** `topic` exists, I even tried to create a new topic but the result did no change.

Has anyone worked with this API who can kindly give me a hand please?

Comment: What Java version are you using? Are you using v1-rev20210723-1.32.1 of the google-api-services-mybusinessnotifications dependency?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. yes I used that version and I have tried also with <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-mybusinessnotifications</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev20220205-1.32.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: So when you go to the method implementation is the IDE able to find the implementation? (public GetNotificationSetting getNotificationSetting(java.lang.String name) throws java.io.IOException {....})

Comment: yes, it is defined: public GetNotificationSetting getNotificationSetting(java.lang.String name) throws java.io.IOException {
      GetNotificationSetting result = new GetNotificationSetting(name);
      initialize(result);
      return result;
    }

Comment: I found the problem, mybusinessNotif should be of type MyBusinessNotificationSettings. But now the problem is that google is just responding me with the account name and no notifications, I guess something is missing for example readMask which I have no idea how to write it. I am going to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the response, I needed to create a new pub/sub topic with the new name:
[image: Creating new pub/sub topic]

and then going to cloud shell: [image: cloud shell]

Assign the permission

> gcloud config set project ‘project_id’
> [image]

Finally, we should give at least pubsub.topics.publish permissions to mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com. if you do not have already, create it by clicking on the **Add Entities** button

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the Java client library, updating works like this:

```
List<String> notificationTypesList = Arrays.asList("GOOGLE_UPDATE", "NEW_REVIEW",
        "UPDATED_REVIEW");
    
NotificationSetting content = new NotificationSetting()
        .setNotificationTypes(notificationTypesList)
        .setPubsubTopic(pubSubTopic);

UpdateNotificationSetting updateNotificationSetting = myBusinessNotificationSettings
        .accounts().updateNotificationSetting(notificationSettingPath, content)
        .setUpdateMask("notificationTypes,pubsubTopic");
```

---

Via the OAuth Playground, the equivalent request would be:

`PATCH /v1/accounts/123456789012345678901/notificationSetting?updateMask=notificationTypes,pubsubTopic`

Body:

```
{
    "notificationTypes": [ "GOOGLE_UPDATE", "NEW_REVIEW", "UPDATED_REVIEW" ],
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic-name"
}
```

If you have access to the GBP APIs and to that location group and there is a GCP project with that topic, this should definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, There is an Error: > \"Request contains an invalid argument.\",\n    \"reason\" : \"badRequest\"\n  } ],\n  \"message\" : \"Request contains an invalid argument.\",\n  \"status\" : \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n}","statusMessage":"Bad Request","statusCode":400. Which version of maven are you using?

Comment: Should work now, setNotificationTypes expects a List<String>

Comment: yes I wrote something like : List<String> notificationTypes =new ArrayList<String>();
      notificationTypes.add("GOOGLE_UPDATE");
      notificationTypes.add("NEW_REVIEW");
but even in console google I have aforementioned error.

Comment: I'm using Maven v3.8.2.

Comment: Can you try via the OAuth Playground? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request

Comment: no the same problem is there too, but would you please write me the dependency in maven you are using? as far as I search the lastest for google notifications is <dependency> <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-services-mybusinessnotifications</artifactId> <version>v1-rev20220205-1.32.1</version> </dependency>

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm using version v1-rev20210723-1.32.1 of the dependency you mentioned.

Comment: Is that where you copy pubsub? https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/...?

Comment: would you please write me the syntax in playground? how do you specify the pubsub and notificationstype. thanks a million

Comment: Once you set the method to PATCH, you can click on "enter request body" and paste the body as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Finally I understood what was my problem, I was using the old pubsub which was using by the old version. in error details it was written SHARES_PUBSUB_TOPIC_MESSAGE_ACROSS_VERSIONS. Creating a new one solved the problem.

Comment: Hello again, sorry I stuck in the same problem and I do not know how I resolved it, I do not know how to set pubsub for recieiving notifications for my locations

Comment: That is not a lot to go on. As always, state what you have tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: I have updated my question with new code and the error